# Fetching group name from MUC invitation in android smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack, multiuserchat

I am using smack library for implementing Multi user chat in android application. I am able to receive invitation for group and able to join using the following invitation listener.

```
   InvitationListener mBilateralInvitationListener = new InvitationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invitationReceived(Connection conn, final String room, String inviter, String reason, String password, Message message) {
            final MucInvitation mucInvitation = new MucInvitation(conn, room, inviter, reason, password, message);

            // Here is my code for accepting muc request. Needed here to identify the group name

            );
        }

    };
```

Here i would like to know the group name but group name i am not receiving in invitation. Please let me know how to fetch group name from the invitation or let me know the way how can we fetch group name in android smack.

Note: I already tried tried to fetch group name from my `MultiUserChat.java` object (`getRoom(), getRoomInfo(,)`) but it is not returning the actual group name instead it is returning as mentioned below.

```
groupchat-04379f6acf3b2525befa93c4b0eaf108@conference.myprovider.net
```

Comment: `room.getRoom().getLocalpart();` check out this. this may help to get roomName.

Comment: Thanks @KuLdipPaTel for your reply. In my case i dont have method like getLocalpart() on getRoom() as it is a string. Here is my MultiUserChat.java getRoom().                                      
implementation public String 'getRoom() {     return room; }'